# Filtering server according to multiple conditions

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a database containing games and their servers. I want to make my program filter the database according to game and server location, and game type, but I don't seem to reach my goal :(.
for example i want it to show Minecraft servers which are located in UK(within the database)

I'm building a `Windows Forms` application.

Here's chunk of the code:

```
private void filter(string cOULMN,TextBox box)
{
   DataView dvtble = tbl1.DefaultView;
   dvtble.RowFilter = (cOULMN+ " like '%" + box.Text + "%'");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     filter("Game", textBox4);
     filter("Location", textBox3);
     filter("Game Type", textBox2);
}
```

Comment: If you dump your data into a class of some sort, you could use Linq to pretty easily accomplish this. On a side note, maybe creating your dataview like this might also help. `DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable);`

Comment: @Timmy i tried it but didn't make any difference :(

Comment: What columns does your database contain?

Comment: @Timmy https://s32.postimg.org/qc2kcn87p/SVS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I would make a class to hold all your Database information

```
public class Games
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GameName { get; set; }
    public string ServerLocation { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
}
```

Next I would make a List of `Games` to hold all your database items

```
private List<Games> Game = new List<Games>();
```

From here populate the List using that information from the database.  There are tons of ways to do this.  This is just one option.

```
foreach (DataRow d in DataTableGames.Rows)
{
    Games g = new Games();
    g.ID = d.Field<int>("ID");
    g.GameName = d.Field<string>("Game");
    g.ServerLocation = d.Field<string>("ServerLocat");
    g.IP = d.Field<string>("iP");
    Game.Add(g);
}
```

After you have your list populated with all the fields from the database, you can use LINQ to essentially filter.  In my example, I'm using a button like you originally did, but I'm putting mine into a datagridview for visibility.  You can do whatever you please with it.

I'm also only filtering using a ServerLocation textbox and a GameName textbox.  You can decide what and how you would like to filter using LINQ queries. LINQ is much more powerful than this example shows.

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Game.Where(l => l.ServerLocation.ToUpper() == txtLocationFlt.Text.ToUpper() 
                                            && l.GameName.ToUpper() == txtGameFlt.Text.ToUpper()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanx for that , i weren't aware of LINQ capabilities :D